# Is it wrong to call component methods passed as arguments inside of redux actions?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, redux, coding-style, redux-thunk

I'm struggling with one task I've been appointed to and the only workaround I found is to call the action argument callback inside the action. Is this a bad idea from a design point of view, because the code itself works and passes numerous tests? The general purpose of this solution is to somehow trigger the component function when a certain logic is being followed.

```js
export function myAction(componentClb: () => void): any {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<AppStore>): void => {
    someRESTAPIcall()
      .then((condition) => {
        condition
          ? dispatch(anotherActionThatTakesCallbackAsArgument(componentClb))
          : componentClb();
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        dispatch(myErrorAction());
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Why can't you update the state in the component, if that state property is true. call the component method

Answer (score 0):

The biggest mistake about this is to take React components as functional classes. Components really are just to handle the WHAT and HOW of page rendering. Anything outside of rendering logics should be removed from it.

Instead of working as callback, this `anotherActionThatTakesCallbackAsArgument` should update the redux store.

The container that componentClb belongs to should be connected to redux store and selects the fields from the stores, and pass these fields to componentClb as props, so that componentClb can handle the rendering based on the response of `myAction`

With the info you provided, it's hard to give a concrete code example. Maybe describe the scenario you are trying to solve and people are able to give you more direct feedbacks.